# Python patch.object decorator can't access method of class

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock

I have a test case below:

```
class Foo(unittest.TestCase):

    @staticmethod
    def my_method():
        ...

    def test_01(self):

        with patch.object(bar, 'method_to_be_mocked', side_effect=Foo.my_method):
            test_stuff()


    def test_02(self):

        with patch.object(bar, 'method_to_be_mocked', side_effect=Foo.my_method):
            test_stuff()


     ... ...
    def test_10(self):

        with patch.object(bar, 'method_to_be_mocked', side_effect=Foo.my_method):
            test_stuff()
```

Basically I'm using Foo.my_method to mock `method_to_be_mocked` The above is working fine, but as you can see I have 10 such test cases and I don't want to write "with patch.object ..." ten times. Therefore I want to use decorator and do something like this:

```
@patch.object(bar, 'method_to_be_mocked', side_effect=Foo.my_method):
class Foo(unittest.TestCase):

    @staticmethod
    def my_method():
        ...

    def test_01(self):
            test_stuff()


    def test_02(self):
            test_stuff()


     ... ...
    def test_10(self):
            test_stuff()
```

But it's telling me that `Foo` is not defined?

Comment: Why don't you define my_method outside of class?

Comment: Mock it in the setUp method.